# How to get rankings for an abbreviated product name without having it on the site?

Tags: seo, keywords

My company has recently renamed & rebranded its two software products and has come across a snag with the naming. One of the products is fairly routinely abbreviated by our customers to a name that our marketing department doesn't want used in any collateral. If it helps, here's the type of product name and abbreviation I'm talking about:

*Franklin DP for Cats*

becomes

*Franklin DPC*

(I've not used the real name, as, frankly, it's a bit embarrassing that we can't use the abbreviated form that our customers seem to prefer.)

Thing is, we still want to make sure that our site shows high in search results for that abbreviated form. I really don't want to do anything that might be viewed as "gaming" by the search engines, but equally, I need to avoid putting the term into the site.

So... **what's the best way to make sure that we still get the rankings?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to put the term onto your website. I have come across plenty of examples where a page ranks for a search term / keyword that it doesn't contain. Google is smart enough to take the keywords contained in the anchor text and apply those to the page in question. It is also smart enough to interpret common abbreviations.

Comment: It's not so much links to the site that I'm concerned about (my original title was rightly corrected by Stephen Ostermiller). In fact, I doubt many people will actually *link* to the site using "Franklin DPC". It's more that I need *searches* for "Franklin DPC" to show our site high in the results.

Comment: In that case, you could attempt to build a few links to that particular page with "Franklin DPC" as the anchor text. Other than that, you'll need to rely on Google's interpretation of what the term "Franklin DPC" means. What about internal links to the page?

Comment: Wouldn't that be interpreted as an attempt to game the system? c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bomb

Comment: @MalRoss In this case, "Franklin DPC" is clearly related to "Franklin DP for Cats", is it not? From that article, it says "The terms Google bomb and Googlewashing refer to the practice of causing a web page to rank highly in search engine results for unrelated or off-topic search terms by linking heavily."

Comment: Also, is using "Franklin DPC" in the title tag out of the question?

Comment: Fair enough, I get that it IS related, but it's presumably a bot doing the checking, so I'd imagine it's a question of whether the bot would see that as clearly related. Also, to answer your other question, yeah, using Franklin DPC in the title tag is out of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15906/discussion-between-mal-ross-and-wexford).